# Мешает апостроф

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void sort(string titls[], int n);
bool isconsist(string titls[], const string &f, int first, int last);

int main()
{
    ifstream ifile("SetList.txt");
    if (!ifile)
    {
        cout << "Cannot open file";
        return 1;
    }
    string titls[25];
    string tit;
    int i{0};
    cout << "Reading SetList.txt file into array\n";
    while (getline(ifile, tit))
    {
        titls[i] = tit;
        i++;
    }
    ifile.close();

    cout << "Sorting array\n";
    sort(titls, i);
    cout << "Sorting done\n";

    string find;
    cout << "Please enter a song or END to terminate: ";
    getline(cin, find);
    while (find != "END")
    {
        if (isconsist(titls, find, 0, i))
            cout << find << " is on the set list\n";
        else
            cout << find << "  is NOT on the set list\n";

        cout << "Please enter a song or END to terminate: ";
        getline(cin, find);
    }
    cout << " Program ends";
    return 0;
}

void sort(string titls[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i != n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j != n - i - 1;j++)
        {
            if (titls[j] > titls[j+1])
                swap<string>(titls[j], titls[j + 1]);
        }
    }
}

bool isconsist(string titls[], const string &f,int first, int last)
{
    int middle = (first + last) / 2;
    if (titls[middle] == f)
        return true;
    else if (first == middle)
        return false;
    else if (titls[middle] > f)
        last = middle - 1;
    else
        first = middle + 1;
    return isconsist(titls, f, first, last);
}
```

Файл:

```
Green Onions
Hold On, I’m Coming
Night Train
Respect
Ninety-Nine and a Half
The Thrill Is Gone
Soul Man
```

Не находит название: Hold On, I’m Coming, но в режиме отладки находит... Я понял, что это из-за апострофа. Можно это как-то пофиксить?

Comment: а зачем сортировку и бинарный поиск делать ручками?

Comment: По заданию так.

Comment: @KoVadim что бы понимать как работает все это, а не просто юзать готовые велосипеды без понимания как, зачем и почему

Comment: std::sort - велосипед? интересно, интересно. А std::vector - это тоже велосипед? а компилятор?

Comment: Какова семантика вашего параметра `last` в `isconsist`? При первом вызове вы туда передаете общее количество элементов, т.е. это индекс **за последним** элементом. Однако при рекурсивных вызовах вы передаете именно **индекс последнего** элемента диапазона. Так все так что это за индекс: "за последним" или "последний"?

Comment: @AnT, спасибо, что указали на неточность, но Hold On I'm Coming всё равное не находится.

Comment: я проверял у себя - все находится. Скорее всего где то лишний пробел.

Comment: @KoVadim: У меня тоже все нашлось. Однако грубая ошибка с `last` в коде все таки присутствует.

Answer (score 0):

Какова семантика вашего параметра `last` в `isconsist`?

При первом вызове вы в качестве `last` передаете общее количество элементов, т.е. индекс *за последним элементом* диапазона поиска. Однако при последующих рекурсивных вызовах вы в качестве `last` можете вдруг передавать именно индекс *последнего элемента* диапазона поиска. Так все таки что такое `last`: это "индекс за последним" или "индекс последнего"?

Эта каша в трактовке параметра `last` приводит к неработоспособности функции. Например

```
string titls[] = { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
bool is = isconsist(titls, "B", 0, 4);
```

возвращает `false` именно из-за этой ошибки. И никаких "мешающих апострофов" не надо.

Comment: То есть, Кнут в очередной раз оказался прав - не все могут написать бинарный поиск и не все могут его правильно использовать (а это уже мое уточнение)